# AJAX Form Post PreventDefault Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple HTML document with a form I would like to post to the server without leaving the page. I've Googled around the internet all day trying to figure out how to get this to work and I've come up with the following code:

```
<body>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#newResource').submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'scripts/script.php?new-resource=1',
                data: $('#newResource').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                }
            });
            return false;

        });

    });
    </script>

    <form id="newResource" class="form-basic" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="scripts/script.php?new-resource=1">
        <label><b>Resource Name:</b></label>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" placeholder="Enter the resource name..." name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required="">
        <br>

        <label><b>Resource URL:</b></label>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" placeholder="Enter the resource URL..." name="url" id="url" autocomplete="off" required="">
        <br>

        <label><b>Resource Department:</b></label>
        <p>Select the department this resource should belong to.</p>
        <select class="input-select" name="department" id="department">
            <option value="5">Human Resources</option>
            <option value="1">Information Technology</option>
            <option value="3">Marketing</option>
            <option value="0">No Department</option>
            <option value="6">Purchasing</option>
            <option value="4">Sales</option>  
        </select>
        <br>

        <label><b>Resource Icon:</b></label>
        <p>Select the icon image to be displayed with this resource.</p>
        <select class="input-select" name="icon" id="icon">
            <option value="bell.png">Alarm Bell</option>
            <option value="chat-bubbles.png">Chat Bubbles</option>
            <option value="chronometer.png">Chronometer</option>
            <option value="database.png">Database Icon</option>
            <option value="envelope.png">Envelope</option>
            <option value="folder.png">File Folder</option>
            <option value="analytics.png">Monitor with Line Graph</option>
            <option value="pie-chart.png">Monitor with Pie Chart</option>
            <option value="networking.png">Networking Heirarchy</option>
            <option value="orientation.png">Orientation Arrow</option>
            <option value="server.png">Server Rack</option>
            <option value="settings.png">Settings Gears</option>
            <option value="speedometer.png">Speedomoeter</option>
            <option value="worldwide.png">World Wide Web Globe</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <div style="float: right;">
            <button type="button" onclick="loadPrefs('resources');" class="form-button cancel">Cancel</button>
            <button class="form-button submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

The code is all within the body tag.

The problem is that when I click the submit button I am redirected to the PHP action script. Does the script I have need to be in the head tag instead?

If I remove the action from the form then the script redirects to the same page but no data is submitted.

Here is the PHP script if necessary:

```
if(isset($_GET['new-resource'])){

    // escape the SQL input for security
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']); 
    $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['url']); 
    $department = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['department']); 
    $icon = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['icon']); 

    // Run the SQL query to add the new resource item
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Resources (ID, ResourceName, ResourceURL, IconImg, Department) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$url', '$icon', '$department');";
    $conn->query($sql);

    // Close the SQL connection
    $conn->close();

}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is not working. Any thoughts and feedback are appreciated.

Comment: The preventDefault works for me, did you check your console for errors?

Comment: No errors in the Apache logs. I've tried the page in Chrome, Safari, and FireFox on Mac OS X and Chrome, Edge, and IE in Windows 10. All do the same thing. Maybe a server misconfig?

Comment: I meant the browser dev tools console - if your e.preventDefault() is not working and the form is submitted directly, it has to be a Javascript error.

Comment: Ah, no, there are no errors in any of the browser consoles.

Comment: You could put some alerts in your code to see if document ready has been fired, and if the submit event has triggered the function ... as I wrote above for me everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The important info in your case was "The HTML form elements are added with AJAX". At `$(document).ready()`, the `#newResource` form element did not yet exist, so the event was never bound. In your working example you used event delegation: `$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(e) {...}`, this is the correct way setup event listeners for non-existing elements.

Comment: Nice catch Benni! I somehow missed that sentence. It was buried under all that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is bound to the submit event of the form. By the time the form has been submitted, it's too late to stop the default synchronous HTML form submission.

Bind your handler to the to click event on the submit button, use `event.preventDefault()` and submit the form via Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.submit').click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $('#newResource');
            var action = form.attr('action');
            var data = form.serialize();


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: action,
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                }
            });


        });

    });
```

Please note, the way this is written, it will fire for any click of an element with a class of submit. Since you may have more than one form on your web page and more than one button with a class of submit, it's not good to have the form variable use a hard-coded ID selector.

If the HTML of all your website forms are always coded this same way, with the submit button inside of a div which is nested in the form, you could replace:

```
var form = $('#newResource');
```

with:

```
var form = $(this).parent().closest('form');
```

Now you can wrap that code in a function called "bindForms()" or whatever, and you have a generic recipe for handling all forms, provided that the HTML structure is always the same (or at least, to the extent that the submit button always has a class of submit and is always wrapped in a parent container which is a child of the form.

Comment: I remember I had a similar problem and I solved it by using a <button> el with type="button" attribute, to make the form practically "unsubmittable" without Ajax - however, Taylor V's approach works for me, do you think browsers handle this not always the same way?

Comment: It doesn't matter weather you use an input of type submit, a link or a button. You don't want the form to submit. You want to bind to a click handler, prevent the form from submitting by using preventDefault(), serialize the form, and then POST the form data using $.ajax() or $.post()

Comment: I'm not sure how I would modify the code to do this.

Comment: Updated my code and it still does not perform the desired effect.

Comment: what happens when you click on the submit?

Comment: Same as before. It goes to the PHP script and the script is executed. It doesn't stay on the page.

Comment: That's odd. You definitely changed the event handler to bind to the 'click' event on the button and you're definitely passing the event to the handler and then calling event.preventDefault()? Make sure the JS code is being executed. Maybe put a breakpoint in the click handler so you can verify that it's actually getting called.

Comment: Could this be a server config issue?

Comment: No. Server config will not affect the execution of JavaScript on the client side.Make sure that you JS code is actually executing. Put a breakpoint inside the click handler. If it doesn't stop on the breakpoint, the click handler isn't firing. Are you using HTML5 doctype? If not, you need to put type="text/javascript" in the script tag. Also, the script should either be in an external file, or if embedded in the HTML, it should be in the HTML head or before the closing </body> tag. The later points about script location are just about performance. They won't affect whether the code works

Comment: I added a debugger to the click handler and the Dev console does not catch it. So it seems the click handler is not being executed. I put the code in jsfiddle and it also does not work. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xx299dm1/)

Comment: Are the form elements present in the initial page load or are they added later via Ajax? If it's the latter, use a delegated binding. Also check for typos in you code. (For example, typos in class name) also, make sure jQuery is loading. Check JS console for errors, too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to get this following code to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(e) { 

    debugger;

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).parent().closest('form');
    var action = form.attr('action');
    var data = form.serialize();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: action,
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            loadPrefs('resources');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML form elements are added with AJAX but so was the script element. I moved the script element to the top of the page so that it is static and no longer loaded with the form.